# PHP - Add transparent PNG to GIF dynamically

Tags: php, watermark, php-gd

I am trying to do a watermark mark with the php code, and everything seems to work fine, until I put a transparent PNG file to a GIF. This what happens:

[image]

So instead of transparent black watermark, I get this semi solid green thing on the top.
The watermark is
[image]

I use the following php code:

```
    ...
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($filepath);;
    $watermark_image = imagecreatefrompng($wm_filepath);
    imagealphablending($watermark_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($watermark_image, true);
    imagegif($image, $filepath);
    imagedestroy($image);


    imagecopy($image, $watermark_image, $offset['x'], $offset['y'], 0, 0, imagesx($watermark_image), imagesy($watermark_image) );
```

p.s. I have to mention that I tried to combine different settings using

```
    imagealphablending()
    imagesavealpha()
```

and got no result

**UPD**:

Now I am saving image as a png file. I deleted these two rows `imagealphablending($watermark_image, false);    imagesavealpha($watermark_image, true);` and it worked. However, the transparency of PNG is overlapping GIF. `imagealphablending($image, true);` didn't help. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

GIF files are limited to 256 colours and have a single colour designated as transparent. So you can't have antialiased transparency, nor can you have much antialiasing of any kind.

I suggest saving as PNG instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am trying to save as PNG by using `imagepng($image, $filepath);`, but I have the same result, except that watermark's background is not "transparent" at all now...