# add a watermark on images

Tags: php, image, watermark

I trying to add a watermark, a png with transparent background,  on images (jpg/gif/png/jpeg)...I have 2 files...the first one is watermark.php:

```
<?php
    require 'func/images.func.php';
    if (isset($_FILES['image'])){
         $file_name =       $_FILES['image']['name']; 
         $file_tmp =        $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];   
         $name = explode('.', $file_name);
         if (allowed_image($file_name) === true){
            $file_name = $img_name .'.png';
            watermark_image($file_tmp, 'images-watermark/uploads/' . $file_name);       
         } else{
          echo '<p>no image, or image type not accepted.</p>';
         }
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Choose an image:
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="watermark"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

...and the second one is images.func.php:

```
<?php
    function allowed_image($file_name){
    $allow_set = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    $file_ext =   (explode('.', $file_name));
    $end = end($file_ext);  
    return (in_array($end , $allow_set) === true) ? true : false;   
}

function watermark_image($file, $destination){
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images-watermark/watermarkf.png'); 
    $source = getimagesize($file);  
    $source_mime = $source['mime']; 
    if ($source_mime === 'image/png'){
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);     
    }else if($source_mime === 'image/jpeg'){
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);    
    }else if($source_mime === 'image/gif'){
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);         
    }   
    imagecopy($image, $watermark, 70, 160, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark),imagesy($watermark));  
    imagepng($image, $destination); 
    imagedestroy($image); 
        imagedestroy($watermark);

}
?>
```

...my code works with jpg/png/jpeg format (the images have a watermark with transparent background)...in gif images the watermark has not a transparent background...any tips?
thanks in advance

Comment: Oh wow.. You seem to be lacking **a lot** of indentation here. Please clean that up, so we have a reasonable chance to take a look at your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983557/php-add-transparent-png-to-gif-dynamically

Comment: Also, does OP use imagick? I think it may not be supported by GD

Comment: sorry...but what's OP? thanks

Comment: why are you using XHTML 1.0 instead of html?

Answer (score 1):

GIF images need to be unpacked to full RGB, then mixed, then reindexed to 256 colors. Adding a transparent watermark on top of an image is a great way to make the data impossible to capture in GIF form because you introduced 256 new shades of overlay.

Comment: I can unpacked  gif images to full RGB using Photoshop...but...what does it mean "then mixed" and "then reindexed to 256 colors"? thank you very much indeed

Comment: your overlay image is mixed into the original image's pixels. The original GIF has 256 colors, then you mix in your transparent watermark, and now the image has more than 256 colors, and the palette needs to be remade, losing information in the process. The main takehome lesson, really, is don't use GIF. It's an image format from the days where computer screens only had a handful of colors. Yes, they're small, so are interpolated PNG files, run through pngcrush

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library for this if You don't do it for experimental purpose.
My personal favorite is [PHP Image Workshop](http://phpimageworkshop.com/) or You can use [Imagine](http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) also.